# How to extract specific lines of data from a text file using vba

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Data I am trying to read from]I am trying to extract specific data from a text file into an excel sheet, I can import the data as a whole but want to only extract certain lines of data depending on certain criteria.

```
Sub ReadText()
    Dim myFile As String

    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    Open myFile For Input As #1

    row_number = 0

    Do Until EOF(1) ' Check for end of file.
        Line Input #1, LineFromFile

        LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")

        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 0).Value = LineItems(0)
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 1).Value = LineItems(1)
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 2).Value = LineItems(2)
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 3).Value = LineItems(3)

        row_number = row_number + 1
    Loop

    Close #1 ' Close file.
End Sub
```

EDIT
The criteria I am looking for are"Ana_Input_Data", "Alarms_From_Analogue_SP" and "Motor_Type_1_SCADA_DATA".

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what criteria you are checking for?  Seems like you may need an if statement after Lineitems = .

Comment: You'd add an If...End If to contain the ActiveCell lines.  That If will contain the logic that determines if you're interested in that line.  What are the criteria?

Comment: @Josh In which column should we search criteria ?

Comment: The criteria is in column 3

Comment: @Josh , Maybe try with [if](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57256080/11167163) statement.. This might do the job =)

Comment: Your code is splitting on comma, but your screenshots shows no commas?  Is your file tab-delimited?

Comment: Simplest approach would be to open the file directly into Excel, then use vlookup etc to extract the values you want.

Comment: Sorry it is separated by a tab, I forgot to change it when I was testing other avenues.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add an `if` statement like below..

```
Sub ReadText()
    Dim myFile As String

    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    Open myFile For Input As #1

    row_number = 1

    Do Until EOF(1) ' Check for end of file.
        Line Input #1, LineFromFile

        LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")

If ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 3).Value = "Ana_Input_Data" And ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 3).Value = "Alarms_From_Analogue_SP" And ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 3).Value = "Motor_Type_1_SCADA_DATA" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 0).Value = LineItems(0)
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 1).Value = LineItems(1)
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 2).Value = LineItems(2)
        ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 3).Value = LineItems(3)
    End If
        row_number = row_number + 1

    Loop

    Close #1 ' Close file.
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesnt work, that if statement is referring to the excel sheet rather than the text document.

Comment: @Josh Can you add a screenshot of your text file ?

Comment: I have added a screenshot